# How to set up a flex container as 3 alternating rows that drop content below with media enquiry

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have pieced together this section for my website using flex containers, and it works for the most part. But I do have a few issues. All of the rows are supposed to break down into a single column layout @media 768px. The 1st & 3rd do, but not the second (where the image is aligned to the right instead of the left).

I am totally inexperienced so excuse that. If someone could please help me reformat this so that it works for that row as well, that would be awesome.

I am trying to emulate the exact same section on the following example site:

https://hismileteeth.com/products/colour-corrector

Here is the current code:

```
<style>
  .flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .flex-container > div {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .flex-container-reverse {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .flex-container {
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    .flex-container > div {
      flex: 1;
      max-width: 48%;
    }

    .flex-container:nth-child(even) > div:first-child {
      order: 2;
    }

    .flex-container:nth-child(odd) > div:first-child {
      order: 1;
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-container-reverse">
    <h2>Step 1.</h2>
    <h3>Connect The App</h3>
    <p>Easily pair your phone with the easy-to-use mobile app available for both IOS & Android devices.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <video muted="muted" loop="loop" autoplay="" playsinline="" preload="auto" width="100%">
      <source src="https://cdn.shopify.com/videos/c/o/v/c1ac052147024dd586ec13e1b0e29617.mp4?v=1632715790">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    <video muted="muted" loop="loop" autoplay="" playsinline="" preload="auto" width="100%">
      <source src="https://cdn.shopify.com/videos/c/o/v/c1ac052147024dd586ec13e1b0e29617.mp4?v=1632715790">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container-reverse">
    <h2>Step 2.</h2>
    <h3>Clean</h3>
    <p>Begin your journey into a place you've never seen before and learn what's lurking inside your ear canal. You'll be guided along by a live, real-time display of everything so you can clean with ease.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-container-reverse">
    <h2>Step 3.</h2>
    <h3>Carry on</h3>
    <p>Dispose of the wax you've removed, and enjoy life free from any fear of unsightly ears, or any discomfort and loss of hearing that can come from blockages.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <video muted="muted" loop="loop" autoplay="" playsinline="" preload="auto" width="100%">
      <source src="https://cdn.shopify.com/videos/c/o/v/370fc17aa3554649b393cc86267827ff.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Your code contains a number of spelling errors.